# Datacentre MIgration: can we have same IPs

Tags: ip, migration, datacenter

I am moving my datacentre from the USA to Singapore with a new vendor. Can I have the same IP address which I was using earlier because most of my applications are using IP to connect to my database and also let me know how can I reduce the latency?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the relationship between the ISP's, the site and type of IP allocation and the depth of your pockets - and, of-course the ownership if the IPs.

If you own the IP block, and its large enough then yes, you can move it - however as you ask the question the realistic answer to this question is most likely not.  Moving IP blocks put a burden on many routing tables, and is messy and complex.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Can you please help in approach needed for datacentre migration?
My database connects with applications which are also hosted on same datacentre but as of now only my database will move not other properties.

Comment: I cant talk definitively, there are a mass if variables including database type, latency, data costs and security. In the very limited information you have provided I would be looking to set up a proxy/forwarder for the database on the old IP, pointing the back end if that to the new site and then reprogramming the clients to connect to the new IP (but by domain name if that's possible).

Comment: Reductions in latency are extremely hard to overcome and as you are restricted by the speed of light (which, on good routes makes the majority of delay, taking into account the slowdowns caused by the fiber).  Mitigations are varied but generally require changes client side - like caching, local read-only replicas and batching queries.

Comment: Depending on your connectivity, sometimes using a VPN or tunnel WITH compression between the network hosting the database and the clients can help. As you are likely shipping text and packets with the same SRC and target you can possibly reduce the size of packets being sent which can reduce latency. This would only represent an incremental improvement at best if implemented correctly.

Comment: Another advantage of setting up a VPN is it increases security - you have not mentioned the database type, but you want to be mindful of unauthorized IPs accessing the database, and, depending on its content, encrypting it. A VPN can assist with both these objectives.

Comment: thanks for your detailed analysis. just clear one thing, will this be useful in going for relocating on-premise datacentre migration?

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand the questionIf you are migrating from on-premise chances are your IP range is smaller so you are less likely to be able to take it with you.  On-premise generally implies smaller links which makes compression slightly more valuable.  Other then that, it doesn't really make a huge difference.